# FirefoxDriver: enable plugins

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, functional-testing, selenium-firefoxdriver

I can't find **FirefoxDriver's** option, which equivalents **--always-authorize-plugins** in **ChromeDriver**.

Does FirefoxDriver contain an equivalent option?

P.S.
**--always-authorize-plugins** enables all plugin in **ChromeDriver**.

Comment: did U read firefoxDriver wiki ???

Comment: I don't find information into wiki. But i find the solution.

Answer (score 2):

I find a solution for my problem.

**My Solution:**

1. close firefox
2. open firefox with flag -p. `win + r => "firefox.exe + -p"`
3. create a new firefox profile
4. find full path to the profile
   `%APPDATA%/Mozila/Firefox/Profiles/[profileName]`
5. then I start webDriver with the profile

   `var until = require('selenium-webdriver').until,`
   `firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');`
   `var options = new firefox.Options();`
   `options.setProfile([fullPath]);`
   `var driver = new firefox.Driver(options);`
   `driver.get('www.google.com');`
   `driver.wait(until.titleIs('webdriver - Google Search'), 20000);`
   `driver.quit();`
6. activate need plugins while firefox is open.
7. restart `webDriver`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `"plugin.state.java" = 2` in FireFox Profile